# Magento 2: How can a customer Sign-In/registraion form in checkout page

Tags: checkout, customer, login, redirect, register

While a user who is not logged in, clicks Proceed to checkout, I want them to be taken to the login page. Then, after they've logged in or registered, they should be taken back to the checkout page. 
in **Magento-1** it's possible  app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage.phtml.

```
<?php
          if (!$this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()) {
                 header("Location: /customer/account/login/");
                 exit();
          }
   ?>
```

how can  I do same  task in Magento2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For your Requirement , Better Option is Disable Gust Order.**

> https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/sales/checkout-guest.html

By default, the guest checkout in Magento is enabled and visitors can place an order without registering to the website. Some websites require mandatory login for placing orders, and this default feature should be turned off to disallow guest checkout.

To disable guest checkout, navigate to:

> **Stores> Configuration > Sales section > Checkout > Checkout Options**
>
> **Set Allow Guest Checkout to No**

Comment: ok but get this message after configuring checkout options set to No. **To check out, please sign in with your email address.**

Comment: A Popup Appear having 2 options 1. Login exists customer  2. Create a new customer,it means you need an account to the website to order products

Comment: only getting this one https://i.stack.imgur.com/StbUw.png. i need form sign-in/register.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/q983tb , this is i am testing with my testproject plaese follow this settings https://prnt.sc/q9844p  .. this should work for you

Comment: to enable onepage checkout follow **Admin >> Store >> Configuration >> Sales >> Checkout >> Checkout Options >> Enable Onepage Checkout >> Yes.**

Comment: thanks.  it works as I need. upvoted your answer.
 can you please  refer this link  i am struggling week of the days https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59133698/magento2-need-help-to-dsplay-shipping-address-payment-method-order-review-i