# Magento2: checkout method for one onepage

Tags: checkout, shipping

By default, the guest checkout in Magento is enabled and visitors can place an order without registering to the website. Some websites require mandatory login for placing orders, and this default feature should be turned off to restrict the guest checkout.

[image: cking]

Comment: Please explain a bit more what do you want?

Comment: Mohit : please visit this link  actual issue is there https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/298348/magento-2-how-can-customer-sign-in-registraion-form-in-checkout-page/298352#298352